# Using Smarty PHP and need a sub system (standalone)

Tags: php, smarty

I am wanting to create a sub-folder in my main application but still allow the stand alone app to access smarty framework.

I have created the sub folder called "admin". However I don't know if I need to include it in my setup file.

```
<?php
require_once(SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php');

class Smarty_EVENT extends Smarty {

  function __construct()
  {

    // Class Constructor.
    // These automatically get set with each new instance.

    parent::__construct();

    $this->setTemplateDir('templates/');
    $this->setCompileDir('templates_c/');
    $this->setConfigDir('configs/');
    $this->setCacheDir('cache/');

    $this->caching = Smarty::CACHING_LIFETIME_CURRENT;
    $this->assign('app_name', 'EVENT');
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: If you are in subfolder, then just add `../` to your path. So something like `../smarty/Smarty.class.php` or `../'. SMARTY_DIR .'Smarty.class.php`

Comment: Why are you using folders instead of routes? (Take a look at Slim framework, it works nicely with smarty)